# align ImageView 10dp left from center of Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

Hi I want to position an ImageView which 10dp from centre of the layout. please suggest me to do it. I am using RelativeLayout.

Comment: you just have to add a margin...

Comment: have you tried marginLeft="10dp" ?

Comment: yeah i tried but its not working

Comment: The correct answer as specified by Chintan is to use padding, not margin, as in: `android:paddingLeft="10dp"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
   android: marginLeft="10dp"
```

Further you should read this:

[RelativeLayout - Developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)

Answer (score 3):

Try Following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  //   <--Sets to Horizontally center 
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"    //   <--Sets to Vertically center
            android:paddingRight="10dp"    //   <---  Sets space of 10dp at rigth, so displays to left
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```